# running unit tests causes .NET Core Host to stop working

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2019

This just started happening.  I've been running my tests successfully for weeks but all of a sudden I get this error (see screenshot):

[image]

When I debug, it takes me to places in my mocks where I'm setting up GUIDs.  I've tried commenting those out and then it fails on other things.  What's weird is that I can build and run the solution just fine in my browser, it's only my test project that is causing this issue.

I have rebooted, doesn't fix it.  I have another solution that is scaffolded almost identically to this one that is running the tests just fine.

...not really sure where to look next?